# how to save as a variable in preg_replace the content selected by the regex pattern?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

In

```
 $Content = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $Content);
```

How i can set in a variable 
      the difference  between the $content before and after the action of preg_replace ?

EDIT

in my case $content is a string i reckon and look like this

```
    <span style="color: #888888;"><img class="wp-image-3164 alignleft" style="color: #333333; margin: 5px;" alt="Modif 2" src="http://blablabla" width="200" height="132" />Rejoignez-nous en<strong> Egypte</strong> et découvrez une des mers les plus chaudes au monde, avec une <strong>visibilité remarquable</strong> et une grande variété d'espèces aquatiques endémiques. Safaga (port Egyptien) ouvert sur la Mer Rouge, situé à 45 minutes de l’aéroport d’Hurghada, est réputé pour son atmosphère non polluée, ses dunes de sable noir et sa <strong>tranquillité</strong>.</span>
```

the regex remove some images from it

Comment: Are you dealing with a string or an array? Also, what differences - length, character range, full on word/sentence diffing?

Comment: Sample input and output would be helpful here.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP $content is a string

Comment: If you just want to see if the img tag has been removed, just save the return value of `preg_replace` to `$newContent` then do `if($Content == $newContent) { /* replacement did nothing */ }`

Comment: no i want to place the new content somewhere else in the page

Comment: gettype($content) returns null !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback) allows you to use a function in your preg_replace 2nd parameter. In that function you can now deal with the match(es) found.

```
$removed_imgs = array();
$content = '<span style="color: #888888;"><img class="wp-image-3164 alignleft" style="color: #333333; margin: 5px;" alt="Modif 2" src="http://blablabla" width="200" height="132" />Rejoignez-nous en<strong> Egypte</strong> et découvrez une des mers les plus chaudes au monde, avec une <strong>visibilité remarquable</strong> et une grande variété d\'espèces aquatiques endémiques. Safaga (port Egyptien) ouvert sur la Mer Rouge, situé à 45 minutes de l’aéroport d’Hurghada, est réputé pour son atmosphère non polluée, ses dunes de sable noir et sa <strong>tranquillité</strong>.</span>';
$content = preg_replace_callback('#(<img.+? />)#',function($r) {
    global $removed_imgs;
    $removed_imgs[] = $r[1];
    return '';
},$content);
//Can now loop through all $removed_imgs
```

All matches for the supplied regex will be removed from the original string, but also added to the `$removed_imgs` array.

Comment: this looks great ... i replaced $removed[] by $removed_imgs[] ..is that right? the problem is that it works with this defined content but not the content from the back office of wordpress grr

Comment: gettype($content) returns null !?

Comment: @Matoeil Yea, sorry renamed the variable after I wrote the code, missed an instance.

Comment: @Matoeil As long as the string is working okay and not erroring I wouldn't worry too much about `gettype` - it could be an encoding issue. Maybe `is_string($Content)` returns something different. Also note that variable are case sensitive, `$content` is not `$Content`

Comment: u are a genious , i managed to make it working . my $content was not right . i needed to use the wordpress function $content=get_the_content() to have a proper string containing my back office content before making this preg_replace_callback treatment

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use: [**`xdiff_string_diff`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xdiff-string-diff.php) function:

```
$repl = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $Content);
$diff = xdiff_string_diff($Content, $repl);
```

Comment: Call to undefined function xdiff_string_diff() !?

Comment: This is PECL extension, see how it can be installed: http://www.php.net/manual/en/xdiff.installation.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_match_all` before preg_replace.
Something like this:

```
preg_match_all($regex,$Content,$matches);
$Content = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $Content);
$diff = $matches;
```

$matches is Array.

Comment: that is the thing i don't understand .i have done that and print_r($diff) returns an empty array

Comment: the regex is ok though because the preg_replace do its job